# in string spec. symbol, php

Tags: php

how to see in string all spec symbols?

Examples: space, new line, tab and t.t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know exactly, what you mean by "see".

You can use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all) with the *PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE* -Flag and you will get any occurence. You can then use this to do, what you like. If you really just want to see "something", use Pekkas solution.

```
$string = str_replace(array("\t","\n"," "),array('<TAB>','<NEWLINE>','<SPACE>'), $string);
```

Its exactly the same, but in one call.

Update: [addcslashes()](http://php.net/addcslashes)

```
$string = addcslashes($string, "\n\t\r ");
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't wish replace. I wish put in display (show) special (hidden) symbol.

Comment: Because they are special characters, they are not visible at all. So if you want to see something, you must make them visible by replacing them with something visible. Another usefull funtion is addcslashes(). I will update my answer

Comment: @lolaola that is not possible: You will need to replace them to make them visible, or view them in an editor that shows them to you (but that leaves the realm of PHP).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()` to make the characters of your choice visible:

```
$string = "Insert here a string that contains spaces, newlines, tabs";

$string = str_replace("\t", "<TAB>", $string);
$string = str_replace("\n", "<NEWLINE>", $string);
$string = str_replace(" ", "<SPACE>", $string);
```